# Checkbox / Button Tap events are not triggering in Visualforce within Salesforce1 Mobile and iOS8

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile

With the new iOS8, certain form elements are not triggering events within Salesforce1 using Visualforce.  For instance:

```
<button id="submitButton" enabled="false">submit</button>
```

Will not trigger a click event.  This is a known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5hOAAS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the success post, the following JavaScript will fix the issue:

```
    (function(){try{var a=navigator.userAgent; 
if((a.indexOf('Salesforce')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1||a.indexOf('iPad')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('OS/8')!=-1||a.indexOf('OS 8')!=-1)&&(a.indexOf('Safari')==-1)){ 
var s=document.createElement('style'); 
s.innerHTML="html,html body{overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;}body{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;}"; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}}catch(e){}})(); 

var ua=navigator.userAgent; 
if((ua.indexOf('Salesforce')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('iPhone')!=-1||ua.indexOf('iPad')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('OS/8')!=-1||ua.indexOf('OS 8')!=-1)&&(ua.indexOf('Safari')==-1)){ 
function IOS_SCROLL_BOOTSTRAP() { 
var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.children), 
placeholder = document.createElement('section'), 
fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(), 
styles, 
width, 
height; 
children.forEach(function(c){fragment.appendChild(c);}); 
placeholder.appendChild(fragment); 
styles = [ 
'width:100%;', 
'height:', (window.screen.height - 42), 'px;', 
'position: absolute; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' 
].join(''); 
placeholder.style.cssText = styles; 
document.body.appendChild(placeholder); 
} 
window.addEventListener('load', function (e) { 
IOS_SCROLL_BOOTSTRAP(); 
}); 
}
```

For easy access, I've set this up via a bitly/heroku: https://bit.ly/vf_ios8_fix